# How to get statistics on time MySQL spent updating indexes during a new row insertion

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance

I'm trying to figure out how multiple indexes are actually affecting insertion performance for MySQL InnoDB tables.

Is it possible to get information about index update times using performance_schema?

It seems like there are no instruments for stages that may reflect such information.

Comment: Test it with and without index. Then compare the times.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It's not that easy to drop an index on production server :)

Comment: With or without droping indexes, I would never run INSERT tests on a production server. That is one reason why test server exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there is something in performance_schema, it would be incomplete.

Non-UNIQUE secondary indexes are handled thus:

1. An `INSERT` starts.
2. Any `UNIQUE` indexes (including the `PRIMARY KEY`) are immediately checked for "dup key".
3. Other index changes are put into the "change buffer".
4. The `INSERT` returns to the client.

The Change Buffer is a portion of the buffer_pool (default: 25%) where such index modifications are held.  Eventually, they will be batched up for updating the actual blocks of the index's BTree.

In a good situation, many index updates will be combined into very few read-modify-write steps to update a block.  In a poor case, each index update requires a separate read and write.

The I/O for the change buffer is done 'in the background' as is the eventual write of any changes to data blocks.  These cannot be realistically monitored in any way -- especially if there are different clients with different queries contributing to the same index or data blocks being updated.

Oh, meanwhile, any index lookups need to look both in the on-disk (or cached in buffer_pool) blocks *and* the change buffer.  This makes an index lookup faster or slower, depending on various things unrelated to the operation in hand.

Comment: Does the same process happen in Slave servers (in Master - Slave replication) ? When a particular session does some INSERT (or any other DML) on the Master; does the same process about batching changes into Change Buffer happen ? Reason I am asking is that people suggest Read-Write load separation between Slave-Master; but if Slave server undergoes the same process, then how does it really standout ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - All DML operations happen on all servers (Master, and Slaves).  And most of the effort is also replicated.  Row-Based-Replication avoids replicating some of the overhead.  But still, the indexes need to be updated.

Comment: Makes sense, but then how come a Read-only Slave performs better than Master server, when we do the same Select query on either of them. I am experiencing this; my earlier understanding was that Master continuously undergoes DML operations, thus making read slow (due to locking etc); and replication handles data consistency through some different means (like some sort of binary file syncing.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Typically, a lot more is going on on the Master.  Eg: `SELECT FOR UPDATE` preceding an update; Lack of good indexes in `UPDATE`; etc.  This leads to locks lasting longer on the Master.